# invalid jump destination error in a contract execution

Tags: solidity, web3js, decentralized-exchange

I am trying to swap dai to eth in Rinkeby testnet using the Uniswap smart contracts.

I get the `invalid jump destination` error and the transaction fails. I do have enough ether in my account.

Any idea what the issue is here? Thank you in advance...!

```
import Web3 from "web3";
import EthTx from "ethereumjs-tx";

// declare a const variable for dai exchange contract address and its abi
const daiExchangeAddress = "0x77dB9C915809e7BE439D2AB21032B1b8B58F6891";
const daiExchangeAbi =
  '[{"name": "TokenPurchase", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "buyer", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_sold", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought", "indexed": true}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "EthPurchase", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "buyer", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_bought", "indexed": true}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "AddLiquidity", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "provider", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_amount", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "token_amount", "indexed": true}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "RemoveLiquidity", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "provider", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_amount", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "token_amount", "indexed": true}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "Transfer", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_from", "indexed": true}, {"type": "address", "name": "_to", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value", "indexed": false}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "Approval", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_owner", "indexed": true}, {"type": "address", "name": "_spender", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value", "indexed": false}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "setup", "outputs": [], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 175875}, {"name": "addLiquidity", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "min_liquidity"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 82605}, {"name": "removeLiquidity", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "amount"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 116814}, {"name": "__default__", "outputs": [], "inputs": [], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function"}, {"name": "ethToTokenSwapInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 12757}, {"name": "ethToTokenTransferInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 12965}, {"name": "ethToTokenSwapOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 50463}, {"name": "ethToTokenTransferOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 50671}, {"name": "tokenToEthSwapInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 47503}, {"name": "tokenToEthTransferInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 47712}, {"name": "tokenToEthSwapOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 50175}, {"name": "tokenToEthTransferOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 50384}, {"name": "tokenToTokenSwapInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 51007}, {"name": "tokenToTokenTransferInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}, {"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 51098}, {"name": "tokenToTokenSwapOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_eth_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 54928}, {"name": "tokenToTokenTransferOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_eth_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}, {"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 55019}, {"name": "tokenToExchangeSwapInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "exchange_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 49342}, {"name": "tokenToExchangeTransferInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}, {"type": "address", "name": "exchange_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 49532}, {"name": "tokenToExchangeSwapOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_eth_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "exchange_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 53233}, {"name": "tokenToExchangeTransferOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_eth_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}, {"type": "address", "name": "exchange_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 53423}, {"name": "getEthToTokenInputPrice", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_sold"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 5542}, {"name": "getEthToTokenOutputPrice", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 6872}, {"name": "getTokenToEthInputPrice", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 5637}, {"name": "getTokenToEthOutputPrice", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_bought"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 6897}, {"name": "tokenAddress", "outputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1413}, {"name": "factoryAddress", "outputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1443}, {"name": "balanceOf", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_owner"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1645}, {"name": "transfer", "outputs": [{"type": "bool", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_to"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 75034}, {"name": "transferFrom", "outputs": [{"type": "bool", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_from"}, {"type": "address", "name": "_to"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 110907}, {"name": "approve", "outputs": [{"type": "bool", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_spender"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 38769}, {"name": "allowance", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_owner"}, {"type": "address", "name": "_spender"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1925}, {"name": "name", "outputs": [{"type": "bytes32", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1623}, {"name": "symbol", "outputs": [{"type": "bytes32", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1653}, {"name": "decimals", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1683}, {"name": "totalSupply", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1713}]';

// set up Web3 to use Infura as your web3 provider
const web3 = new Web3(
  new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
    "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/MY_PROJECT_ID"
  )
);

// declare a const variable for your address and private key
const addressFrom = "MY_ADDRESS";
const privKey = "MY_PRIVATE_KEY";

// instantiate the contract
const daiExchangeContract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(daiExchangeAbi), daiExchangeAddress);

// declare const variables to pass to tokenToEthSwapInput function
const TOKENS_SOLD = web3.utils.toHex(0.4*10**18); // 0.4DAI
const MIN_ETH = web3.utils.toHex(5000000000000000); // 0.005ETH
const DEADLINE = 1564531200; // 07/31/2019 @ 12:00am (UTC)

// Create a transaction object for the tokenToEthSwapInput function and encode the abi for it, which will be sent later
const encodedABI = daiExchangeContract.methods.tokenToEthSwapInput(TOKENS_SOLD, MIN_ETH, DEADLINE).encodeABI();

async function constructTransactionObject() {
  const transactionNonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addressFrom);

  const transactionObject = {
    nonce: await web3.utils.toHex(transactionNonce),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(6000000), // 0.000000000006ETH
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(10000000000), // 0.00000001ETH
    to: daiExchangeAddress,
    from: addressFrom,
    data: encodedABI
  }

  return transactionObject;
};

// Signs the given transaction data and sends it.
async function sendSignedTx() {
  const transactionObject = await constructTransactionObject();
  let transaction = new EthTx(transactionObject);
  const privateKey = new Buffer.from(privKey, "hex");
  transaction.sign(privateKey);
  const serializedEthTx = transaction.serialize().toString("hex");
  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(`0x${serializedEthTx}`,
  (error, transactionHash) => {
    if (error) { console.log(`Error: ${error}`); }
    else {
      console.log(`Result: ${transactionHash}`);
    }
  }
  );
}

sendSignedTx();
```

Comment: Invalid Jump exception is due to a problem in the contract's code. Where is it???

Comment: Thank you for your comment! There seems to be [no verified contract](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x77db9c915809e7be439d2ab21032b1b8b58f6891#code) in Etherscan. I asked people in Uniswap a few days ago but no reply so far. I will update the post once I get the reply. I guess it's probably [this code](https://github.com/Uniswap/contracts-vyper/blob/master/contracts/uniswap_exchange.vy#L151) though.

Comment: Do you have enough DAI? Did you approve the exchange address to make transfers?